# VB.NET JSON Array of JSON Array - Deserialize

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net

I have a json return that looks like so:

```
{"coin1":{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"},
 "coin2":{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"},
 "coin3":{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}
 }
```

I am trying to return it into a list of "coinName".

I am doing:

```
Public Class coinName
    Public Vals As cValues
End Class

Public Class cValues
    Public available As String
    Public onOrders As String
    Public btcValue As String
End Class
```

And I am using the following code to deserialize:

```
Dim pData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of coinName))(bals)
```

"bals" being the json return in the form of a string.

I am receiving the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsApplication21.coinName]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path '1CR', line 1, position 7.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I think your JSON isn't structured correctly. JSON arrays should be as follows: `"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]` you shouldn't be using **{}**

Comment: So coming back to the structure i think your still missing the **[]** basically you should have: `"coin3":[{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}]` Try running your code with the corrected JSON see if it works.

Comment: {"coin1":[{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}], "coin2":[{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}], "coin3":[{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}]}

does not work still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root JSON container isn't an array - it's an object with variable property names in the form `"coinN"` for various `N`.  You can deserialize such an object with variable property names into a dictionary:

```
Dim pData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, cValues))(bals)
```

For documentation, see [Serialization Guide : Dictionaries and Hashtables](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dictionarys) and [Deserialize a Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/COjjzA).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if his will help you I don't have much knowledge in JSON with VB.NET but i manage to get the first occurrence of coin. The thing to remember your classes need to have the same name as in JSON:

```
Dim final As String = ""
Dim json As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim coincollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of coinCollection)(json) ' Deserialize array of Post objects
Dim coins = coincollection.coin
If coins.Length = 1 Then ' or whatever condition you prefer
   final = coins(0).available
End If
```

My JSON input is:

```
{"coin":[{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}],
 "coin":[{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}],
 "coin":[{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}]
 }
```

And the two classes I used are:

```
Public Class coinCollection
    Public coin() As coinName
End Class
Public Class coinName
    Public available As String
    Public onOrders As String
    Public btcValue As String
End Class
```

The Array name needs to be the same as in the JSON hence: **coin**

However the wrapper only gets the first **coin** object maybe you can try figure how to read all of it.